# Why does Google not parse my content from firebase database in my Angular project?

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, google-pagespeed

I created a website with Angular 8. I used firebase services to get data and display them. Google search engine does not see my content from firebase.

All pages are parsed, but without the content from firebase. For this reason all my links generated by angular from firebase database are not present.

Google PageSpeed Insights creates a screenshot for every page, but only the website headers are displayed.

Also when I run page insights for a link which should be generated from firestore I get the following error:

> Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. Something went wrong with recording the trace over your page load. Please run Lighthouse again. (NO_FCP) (NO_FCP)

Comment: If you want spiders to properly crawl your SPA web applications (Angular, React, etc.) they need to be rendered server side. https://angular.io/guide/universal

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the fact that the application is a SPA i.e not static and requires bootstrapping. You can test this by using Angular Universal and pre-compile your Angular app on the server.